# Custom SQL Server Views and Database Migration

Tags: sql-server, grails, database-migration

I have a few Views created in SQL Server that I'm using for a SSRS project. However, whenever I try to migration my Grails project, it attempts to drop my SQL views.

I'm using the [database-migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) to perform my migrations.

Why does the plug-in want to drop my SQL views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set my SQL Views to another schema